# convert monad to IO

Tags: haskell, monads

I'd like to use [`finally`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:finally), signature `IO a -> IO b -> IO a`.

However, the operations I wanna use are based on a different monad than `IO` (namely [`Servant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant)'s [`ClientM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/Servant-Client.html#t:ClientM)).

I knew [`liftIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO), but that seems to do the opposite -- `IO a -> m a`.

How can I transform my monads into IOs, or lift `finally` such as to operate on my monads instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that `ClientM` also has a `MonadBaseControl IO ClientM` instance  which is for this sort of thing. For instance, I think the following should typecheck (and can be used with `m ~ ClientM`).

```
finally' :: MonadBaseControl IO m => m a -> m b -> m a
finally' x y = control $ \runInIO -> catch (runInIO x) (runInIO y)
```

## EDIT

Not only does the above typecheck, but it is defined in [`lifted-base` as `finally`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.12/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:finally).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'd have gotten lost trying to find this black magic. I've somehow run into an error actually trying to use its `MonadBaseControl` instance though -- I've posted that as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439760/no-instance-for-trait-thats-already-implemented).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ClientM` must be run at some point with [`runClientM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/Servant-Client.html#v:runClientM), which brings it down to `IO`.

Perhaps the simplest solution—if it happens to fit your case—would be to use `finally` to wrap that resulting `IO` action.