# "No instance for" trait that's already implemented

Tags: haskell, servant

I'd like to use Servant's [`ClientM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/Servant-Client.html#t:ClientM) monad with [`finally`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.12/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:finally)`:: MonadBaseControl IO m => m a -> m b -> m a`, but am faced with error `No instance for (MonadBaseControl IO ClientM)`.

Oddly, this exact instance appears to be [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/Servant-Client.html#t:ClientM) already, be it from an [internal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.13.0.1/docs/src/Servant.Client.Internal.HttpClient.html) module.

Do I need to explicitly import such instances somehow?

Comment: You need to import the module where the `instance` is defined. You however do (well you basically can't) name the instance. It will import all the instances of that module. So something like `import Some.Module()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, I've updated the question with a complication -- the module it is defined in is internal.

Comment: @Tycho Importing any module which (transitively) imports that internal module will do (e.g. importing `Servant.Client` should be enough, from my reading of the source for that module). That said, the module you linked to appears to be exported, so what's the problem? Can you make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to play with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine if, as Daniel said, you import the module that defines the desired instance:

```
Prelude> import Control.Exception.Lifted
Prelude Control.Exception.Lifted> import Servant.Client
Prelude Control.Exception.Lifted Servant.Client> :set -XTypeApplications
Prelude Control.Exception.Lifted Servant.Client> :type finally @ ClientM
finally @ ClientM :: ClientM a -> ClientM b -> ClientM a
```

Comment: I managed to reproduce my issue with this, then realized my versions were behind. Fixing that solved it. Thanks!